# \mu and \epsilon missing in ebgaramond-maths font?

Tags: fonts, latex, pdflatex

I've been searching for ages and now I became totally desperate, as it seems that I am the only (or the first?) one encountering this problem. I am compiling with pdfLaTeX and want to use ebgaramond-maths font (for both text and maths), because I think it just looks wonderful. However, it seems that there are few Greek letters missing, see below. How is this possible? Or am I doing anything wrong?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begin{document}
$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon, \zeta, \eta, \theta, \iota, \kappa, \lambda, \mu, \nu, \xi, \pi, \rho, \sigma, \tau, \upsilon, \phi, \chi, \psi, \omega$
\end{document}
```

What I get is:

[image: greek-letters-output]

I tried changing the font to ebgaramond. This gives me correct full list of Greek symbols, but the font is different (and less beautiful, IMHO).

Comment: OK, so I already found a solution - all I needed was to swap order of the two commands calling the font packages, so instead of

\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

I should use

\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}

Comment: If you swap the order, you get times math font. Why load ebgaramond at all?

Comment: If I call first garamond and then newtxmath, than I get everything in Garamaond without any missing symbols, which is exactly what I need. Although I have no idea why :-)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you get with first loading garamond and then newtxmath?

Comment: Sorry, you were right! In this MWE, swapping the call for fonts really changes the font. However, in the large document where I actually need it - it helped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can switch to either lualatex or xelatex, you can use the opentype Garamond Math font from https://github.com/YuanshengZhao/Garamond-Math like this:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon, \zeta, \eta, \theta, \iota, \kappa, \lambda, \mu, \nu, \xi, \pi, \rho, \sigma, \tau, \upsilon, \phi, \chi, \psi, \omega$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know about this possibility, which I used some years ago before with XeLaTeX. However, I decided to stick to pdfLaTeX and wanted to know what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `newtx` package.  For example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

  \AtBeginDocument{
  \usepackage[vvarbb,ebgaramond,smallerops]{newtx}
}

\begin{document}
$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon, \zeta, \eta, \theta, \iota,
\kappa, \lambda, \mu, \nu, \xi, \pi, \rho, \sigma, \tau, \upsilon,
\phi, \chi, \psi, \omega$
 
\end{document}
```

[image: epsilon test]